# Creating multiple worksheets in Excel using X++

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, x++, axapta

I am currently able to create a new Excel spreadsheet, write to it and save the spreadsheet through X++.

I have a few methods within a new class, each intended to write to a separate worksheet within the workbook.

The first method creates the spreadsheet, writes the data, saves the spreadsheet, and then quits Excel just fine. But within the next method I attempt to open the saved spreadsheet, write to another worksheet (tab), **save** again, and quit Excel.

The second method causes the following error. 
Method **'saveAs'** in COM object of class '_Workbook' returned error code 0x800A03EC () which means: You cannot save this workbook with the same name as another open workbook or add-in. Choose a different name, or close the other workbook or add-in before saving.

Is it possible to create and save multiple Excel worksheets within one Excel workbook in X++?

Comment: Consider showing your code. What version of AX and Excel?

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen Thanks for both replies. Forgot to mention that I am working with AX 2009, Excel 2010 on Windows Server 2008 Standard, 32-bit.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen Been tied up working on other items as this is more of an informational piece, but I have been looking @ some of the code in the SysDataExcelCOM class used by the Data Import/Export for some guidance. I was able to programmatically delete the standard "Sheet 1, Sheet2, Sheet 3" worksheets from my Excel Workbook by studying this class. Will keep you posted... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to Jan for responsing

After reviewing the **SysDataExcelCOM** class, there is a **CreateWorkbook** method which creates the additional worksheets for the Excel Data Definition export. After creating a new similar class method and also declaring my own set of defined names (#define.ExampleExcelWorksheetName('abcSheet') for the Excel Worksheets, I was then able to create the Excel Workbook with multiple worksheets. Then save (SysExcelWorkbook.saveAs) after all of the necessary sheets are created first, rather than open the saved Workboook then adding worksheets per new class method.

Within the other class methods where data is intended to write to the Worksheets, I opened the Workbook created by the new method similar to CreateWorkbook (sysExcelWorkbooks.open(yourExcelFile), then refer to each Worksheet using (sysExcelWorksheet.itemByName) to write the data to the specific Worksheet, then save.

```
excelApplication    = SysExcelApplication::construct();
excelWorkbooks      = excelApplication.workbooks();
excelWorkbooks.open(fileNameSave);
excelWorkbook       = excelWorkbooks.item(1);

//Add styles and fonts
excelStyles = excelWorkbook.styles();
excelStyle  = excelStyles.add("Header");
excelFont   = excelStyle.font();
excelFont.bold(true);

excelWorksheets     = excelWorkbook.worksheets();
excelWorksheet      = excelWorksheets.itemFromName(#declared name of your worksheet);

// Begin Header Row
excelWorksheet.cells().item(1,1).value("value of your choice");
excelWorksheet.cells().item(1,2).value("value of your choice");
excelWorksheet.rows().item(1).style("Header");

excelWorksheet.name("Rename your declared worksheet name or use current name here");
excelCells          = excelWorksheet.cells();
excelCells.range('A:B').numberFormat('@');

//Find you data to write to Excel Worksheet here

excelWorksheet.columns().autoFit();
excelApplication.displayAlerts(false);
excelWorkbook.saveAs(fileNameSave);
excelWorkbook.comObject().save();
excelWorkbook.saved(true);
excelApplication.quit();
```

Going this route worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not a direct answer to your question, but might give you another perspective on creating Excel files.

I tend to use XML and XSLT to create Excel files. You can easily create what you want in Excel and then save the Excel file as XML and then you can apply some XSLT that reads data from another XML file and puts it into the Excel file you want.

You can find a post concerning this topic on my blog : [Using C#, XML and XSLT to create Excel files](http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2009/08/using-c-xml-xslt-to-create-excel-spreadsheet/)

There I create an XML file containing Items and transform that into an Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the idendity of the Excel COM service. See what [others](http://www.hagrin.com/319/exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-excel-net-sql-and-windows-server-2008) have [done](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3ecbc477-a5d9-4033-887b-3e7dbaf2b7cb/).

Comment: I checked out the identify of the Excel COM service, Microsoft Excel Application. I tested the code after setting the identity to "Interactive User" and "Launching User". The same error occurred on both occasions.